# BeforeStories exception

Tags: java, jbehave

I would like to report stacktrace of my exception to the console, so if I have:

```
@BeforeStories
public void init() {
    throw new RuntimeException("omg");
}
```

I would like to have:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: omg
    at com.mycompany.MyClass.init(MyClass.java:69)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: just to clear things, of course not I will throw RuntimeException. I just would like to see if something goes wrong in BeforeStories...

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure I understand what you're trying to achieve since throwing the exception should already log a failure to console.

but if you wanna just print out the exception message and tracestack to console you can do the line below although it's pretty terrible it should give you what you want:

```
@BeforeStories
public void runBeforeAllStories() {
    new RuntimeException("omg").printStackTrace();
}
```

the application will continue running but will output the text below in console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: omg   at
>   jbehave.sample.steps.LifecycleSteps.runBeforeAllStories(LifecycleSteps.java:31)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$MethodInvoker.invoke(StepCreator.java:805)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$BeforeOrAfterStep.perform(StepCreator.java:491)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableSteps.perform(PerformableTree.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performBeforeOrAfterStories(PerformableTree.java:427)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.performStories(StoryManager.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStoriesAsPaths(StoryManager.java:86)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:213)
>     at jbehave.sample.common.StoriesTest.run(StoriesTest.java:161)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)

Answer (score 0):

first of all I appreciate that you want to show your exception in a funny way. You can express your exception like just adding throws Exception to the @BeforeStories method as below.

```
@BeforeStories
public void init() throws Exception{
    throw new RuntimeException("omg");
}
```